Conversion from PDF to image fails in ghostscript
I need to convert the first page of a PDF file into an image using GhostScript, but I cannot manage to get an acceptable output file.
I am calling the C++ library (ver. 10.03.0) directly from C# using  this implementation
The arguments I pass to the sapi_init_with_args are: gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -sOutputFile=output.jpg input.pdf
It completes successfully (EC: 0) and generates the image, but it is wrong.
This is a screenshot of the PDF file I'm using (Link to source),

This is the image generated:

Have you any idea why this is happening?
Thanks to KenS for all the suggestions

It's treating the PDF file as text, not as a PDF file. Which suggests that you are using the Ghostpdl DLL, not the Ghostscript DLL, since Ghostscript can't handle text at all. What is the name of the DLL you are using (and note; it should be 10.03.0, not 10.3.0) ? What messages do you get on the back channel (stderr/stdout) ? Are you using the API directly from C# or are you spawning a process ? You say 'the command I run is ...' and also 'I'm calling the DLL ... from my C# code' so which one are you actually doing ? If you are using code, where is your code ?

You are right, I am using the Ghostpdl so that might be the problem, I’ll update the question in order to provide more clarity.
